# How to ajax submit this form which doesn't have a submit button?

Tags: jquery

I have the following form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
</form>
```

Once a user has clicked the uploadedfile input and selected a file, they then can click this button on a different area of the page:

```
<a id="button">My button</a>
```

How can clicking My button, how can it trigger the upload of the form? Important:  cannot be within the form and can't be an input element. This must also be an ajax style operation with no reloading of the page if possible.

Comment: you should note when you've edited your post in such a way that it would invalidate answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the form an ID (or use one of the many variations to select the form):

```
<form id="myForm" [...] >
```

and with jQuery [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) the form:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

You'll want the submit functionality to be within a click event of the button:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

**Update**

To submit your form using ajax you can do the following:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
      var form = $('#myForm');
        $.ajax({
          url: form.attr('action').val()  ,
          type: 'POST' ,
          data: form.serialize()
        });
    });
```

If you're uploading files as it seems you might be, you might want to look at one of the following jQuery plugins:

- [jQuery Ajax File Upload Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)
- [Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

Comment: Is this possible to do ajax style? I don't want the page to reload. Sorry I wasn't clear. I was hoping for something similar to the .ajax method.

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer whilst you update your question to be ajax related.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that. I can see on the network it submits the input fields of the form but isn't picking up the image. Are you sure this is right? Thanks.

Comment: I guess I am trying to ask, does serialize work with files as well as text

Comment: No, see the bottom of my answer, I've included some links to plugins you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get a reference to the form and then call `.submit` on it:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("form[action='uploader.php']").submit();
});
```

It would be a good idea to give the form an `id` as well so that you can select it with a more mainstream selector such as `$("#theForm")`.

Comment: Is this possible to do ajax style? I don't want the page to reload. Sorry I wasn't clear. I was hoping for something similar to the .ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery trigger function

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("form").trigger('submit');
})​;
```

Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/amQvM/) here

Answer (score 0):

you can do like the above answers, or you can submit the form without even refreshing the page like [HERE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

Comment: Those are text fields though, which is something I already know how to do. I want to do it with a file.

Comment: @Hardworker oh sorry about that! I gotta read more carefully next time! I'll try giving an update later if no one answers :)